# How to get current system DNS resolvers ip-addresses in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to get all current system DNS resolver ip-addresses in codename one?

The classes `NetworkManager` and `ConnectionRequest` don't provide these information.

In general Codename One seems not to provide any way to access a devices communication status information like "Wi-Fi Mac address", "IMEI", "Mobile network type" etc. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like `Socket.getHostOrIP()`?

There is no standardized explicit DNS lookup API though.

Most of these things aren't available across platform or even consistently within the platform. You can use Display's `getProperty` with `"IMEI"`, `"UDID"` & `"MSISDN"`. But that will only have any chance of working on Android and you will probably need to add the [build hint for permissions](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

You can also always use native code calls as explained in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) and the [How Do I?](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) video.

I would suggest that you revisit your need to get these values and evaluate a way around them. E.g most advertisers no longer require them as they aren't provided by all mobile OS's.

Comment: Thank you Shai for confirmation.